# Webserver not listening to ports

Tags: php

**Problem**

I've recently found out that PHP has a built-in webserver which can be used for development purposes. Starting the server with the address "127.0.0.1" and the port "8080" works without any problems and my requests are handled properly. However, if I dare to use the address "localhost" with the same port, the webserver doesn't handle any requests.

**Specs**

1. Windows 10 64-Bit
2. Php 64-Bit Thread-Safe installed
3. MongoDB installed (Not running)
4. IIS Server installed and running
5. MariaDB installed (Not running)

Comment: Can you reword your problem section. It doesn't give an good idea of what you're doing and what specifically isn't working.

Comment: (Sounds a name resolution problem rather than a PHP one.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name resolution for `localhost` is handled by your DNS server which is likely resolving it to the IPv6 address `::1`.

If you run:

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:8080
```

The webserver is running on the IPv4 address but `localhost` resolves to the IPv6 address.

So you can either use `127.0.0.1:8080` in the browser address bar.

Or force the address by un-commenting the following line from `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`:

```
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Or bind the webserver to the IPv6 address (this is what I do):

```
php -S localhost:8080
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) Everything is working as it should now.